# Proper $_SESSION authentication

Tags: php, session

What is the proper way to authenticate users? As in, setting a page whereby only logged in users can view?

Does this work?

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION[username]) || empty($_SESSION[username]) || !isset($_SESSION[id]) || empty($_SESSION[id]))
{
session_destroy();
session_unset();
die('You\'re not authorized to view this page!');
}
?>

<?php
echo"Can I freely, and safely write my content here? Will it be properly authenticated with my code above?";
?>
```

But my question is, if I use the above code, can I freely add my content below the code? And is there any other better way to do this?

I have another code whereby I do a

```
session_destroy();
header("Location: logout.php");
{and then I echo my content below; where logged in users can see}
```

But I'm just wondering if, once I do that, does it mean users will not be able to see my content below?

Thanks!

Comment: Why to destroy session if user aren't authorized to visit some page?

Comment: technically you have full control over the session data, because it is stored on your server, so you don't need to worry (much) about users faking it (at best, they could fake their token to pretend to be somebody else, if they managed to get that token). But I would try to do better checking than that; checking a particular flag like `$_SESSION['allowaccess']`, to avoid accidentally giving permission in some other script years later

Comment: oh and don't forget to use quotes. PHP is rather lax in its syntax, but you could get subtle bugs from using `$_SESSION[username]` instead of `$_SESSION['username']`, especially if you're on an old environment where register_globals is enabled.

Comment: *"Does this work?"* – Have you not tried it?

Comment: Whoops sorry, what I meant was, how do I make a page only accessible to logged in users? Will doing if(!isset($_SESSION[username]) header("location: login.php"); work? Because in my codes, I'll place those codes first, followed by the actual page content. Will the page still load the content for user's not logged in?

Comment: @user2488354 You need to answer your own question first, by trying it out. If something doesn't work, then post your actual errors/difficulties. I don't have time to test your theory. Just try it out ;-)

Comment: It does work, but I'm not sure if theres any loopholes in it. Does PHP codes run line by line? So if I do a header or die above my main content, my main content will be safe?

Comment: @user2488354 Sessions store unique to the server/user cookies and that can't be modified, unless someone hacks into your computer. Look at what the others posted as comments above to give you some added tips. So to make a long story short, yes it will work. You just need to further test it and if you can't access it if you're not logged in, then no one else will. Have a look at the following link, which is what I use along with a token: http://phpro.org/tutorials/Preventing-Multiple-Submits.html --- I merely incuded my own executable code where needed/required.

Comment: @user2488354 An added bit of essential information is, make sure you do not have "output" above your `header('Location...`, otherwise it will generate an error message, such as `headers already sent`. Output can be a mere space, a tab, HTML, etc. above `<?php`

Comment: Oh, and last thing. I've done it in a file called session.php. And I simply include it in pages I want authenticated. But is there a way I can protect my session.php page? Like when I visit the page directly, it shows Failed opening 'inc/connect.php' and stuff. I want it to be inaccessible directly.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, but you are a bit verbose in your strategy. Here is a simpler way.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION['username'])) 
{
  echo "Not allowed."; // possible redirect to login page.
  exit; 
}

//Authenticated stuff here.
```

To logout, just clear the username.

```
$_SESSION['username'] = "";
```

Normally, you don't need to worry about cleaning up the internal PHP session cache. PHP has a periodic script that runs in the background on the server to handle that for you.

Comment: Oh, and last thing. I've done it in a file called session.php. And I simply include it in pages I want authenticated. But is there a way I can protect my session.php page? Like when I visit the page directly, it shows Failed opening 'inc/connect.php' and stuff. I want it to be inaccessible directly.

Comment: Change your includes to a "require_once", and PHP will stop execution when it can't find your file. During deployment, you can turn off error outputs and the user will just see a blank page. If you want it to be completely inaccessible, you can move the file to a directory that is not public or protected by .htaccess